# Изменение битрейта аудио

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Помогите, как сделать при помощи JS и PHP изменение битрейта аудио? Чтобы при загрузке аудио файла на сервер автоматически битрейт изменялся на нужный.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая утилита/программа/набор библиотек `ffmpeg`, позволяющая работать с аудио и видео форматами. Тут предствалена её поддержка на `PHP`

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Добавление 
$ffmpeg = FFMpegFFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg', // path to file ffmpeg
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe', 
    'timeout' => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads' => 12, // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
) , $logger);
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// 
$audio = $ffmpeg->open('uploaded-file-path.mp3');
$format = new FFMpegFormatAudioFlac(); // Есть еще варианты mp3, aac, wav...
$format->on('progress',
function ($audio, $format, $percentage)
    {
    echo "$percentage % transcoded";
    });
$format->setAudioChannels(2)
       ->setAudioKiloBitrate(96); // Изменяйте на нужный 
$audio->save($format, 'output-file-path.flac');
```

---

[Офф сайт ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)

[Установка ffmpeg](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg)

[PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)